# localhost:4200 is a blank page in Angular

Tags: angular

After login, the default link is =>
`http://localhost:4200/dashboard/administration/portfolio`

[image]

If I remove `/portfolio` from the address
`http://localhost:4200/dashboard/administration`

and I press "enter",

[image]

Automatically is displayed, `http://localhost:4200/dashboard/administration/portfolio`, I want to keep this system for all paths.

If I remove `/administration/portfolio` and press `enter`,

[image]

Automatically the page is directed to `http://localhost:4200/dashboard/administration/portfolio`.

So far everything is working perfectly.

**My problem**, if I remove `dashboard/administration/portfolio`.

So the link is `http://localhost:4200/` then `enter`.

I have a blank page, I don't automatically return to `http://localhost:4200/dashboard/administration/portfolio`, I don't understand why?

[image]

I think it's a problem with a route?

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [CanActivateTeam],
    loadChildren: () => import('./views/dashboard/dashboard.module').then((m) => m.DashboardModule),
  },


  {
    path: 'sessions',
    loadChildren: () => import('./views/identity/identity.module').then((m) => m.IdentityModule),
  },
  { path: 'pipes', loadChildren: () => import('./shared/pipes/pipes.module').then(m => m.PipesModule) },

  // others
  {
    path: '**', redirectTo: ''
  },
  
];
```

dashboard-routing.module.ts

```
const DASHBOARD_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,

    children: [
      {
          path: '',
          redirectTo: 'administration',
          pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'administration',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./views/administration/administration.module').then(
            (m) => m.AdministrationModule
          ),
      },
      {
        path: 'market',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./views/market/market.module').then((m) => m.MarketModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'dta',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./views/dta/dta.module').then((m) => m.DtaModule),
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

administration-routing.module.ts

```
export const ADMINISTRATION_ROUTES: Routes = [
 
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdministrationComponent,

    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'portfolio',
      },

      {
        path: 'portfolio',
        component: PortfolioComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'account-opening',
        component: AccountOpeningComponent,
      },

      {
        path: 'corporate-action',
        component: CorporateActionComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'visualization-deposit',
        component: VisualizationDepositComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you any error in console?

Comment: @n_denny: No, I have no errors in my console and the program runs fine

Comment: would you be able to create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular-ivy) with a minimum reproducible problem?

Comment: Use `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true }),` for extra traces

Comment: it could also be the order in whick you are importing the  routing modules.
Since you have a route with "**",  make sure that this module is imported last

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
   path: '',
   redirectTo: 'dashboard',
   pathMatch: 'full'
},
```

Add this to your DASHBOARD_ROUTES.

Thanks to this, your dashboard module will know where to go when loaded.